# Java SecureRandom generate URL like Medium.com (Random 12 characters)

Tags: java, primary-key, secure-random

**Instead** of using the **Long** type do the **Primary key**, I found seems *Medium.com* using 12 characters. Can anyone let me know *the algorithm* or *similar way to create it*.

For example: medium.com/**/nosuchmethoderror-in-log4j-issue-3a80f0c412c

```
Hash (current timestamp + blabla +...) => like: 3a80f0c412c
```

I heard using Java **SecureRandom** quite good but I haven't really understood it. Someone can show me the code? Tks

Comment: Why use a strong random number generator for the functionality of uniformly distributed hash?

Comment: I don't know much about it, you can give your opinion? @alfasin

Comment: Hi `dta`, may I suggest that the primary key is possibly the page name _plus_ the 12 character random string, i.e. the key is actually the entire following: `nosuchmethoderror-in-log4j-issue-3a80f0c412c` ... It is _highly_ unlikely that two posts would then collide, even if someone they had the same exact name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need 12 random characters, you could generate a `UUID` and then take a substring:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
System.out.println(uuid.toString().replaceAll("-", "").substring(0, 12));
```

### Demo

Comment: I know it but I feel it is **not safe**. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @dta.hoan What is "not safe" about this approach?  This seems reasonable based on the information you gave us in the question.

Comment: I was talking about the Primary Key (Database) and SecureRandom. @tim-biegeleisen

Comment: Hmmm...if you need a primary key, why not just an auto increment column?  Side note: There are `4x10^18` combinations with 12 characters from a UUID.

Comment: I feel : `/..how-to-d3e3077f8adb/` user-friendly than `/..how-to-12/`

Comment: @dta.hoan If you read my comment above, I am speculating that a primary key could be a combination of the UUID and the title.  It is highly unlikely that you would ever see a collision there.

Comment: @dta.hoan 12 random characters by itself is not enough to reasonably support a primary key. If your goal is generating a universally unique identifier, use a [Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), a 128-bit value. Ideally use the Version 1 UUID based on a point in time and space using a combination of current moment and a MAC address. If not available, fall-back to using Version 4 where 122 of the 128 bits are randomly generated. Using a good cryptographically-strong implementation should be good enough for most purposes.